# How do I remove myself from a chat?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

So I've been on Stack Overflow for about a month and a half, and have begun to explore more features of the site. When I came across the chats, I thought they'd be interesting to try out, so I went ahead and typed "Hello" in the [Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) chat.

Turns out, there are other Alexs in this chat. And my name also starts with Alex. So whenever someone posts [a message that starts with @Alex](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19701477#19701477), talking to the *other* Alex, I get a notification. It is very annoying. First of all, how can I get out of this chat. Second of all, is there a setting somewhere where I can disable notifications from chat like this one?

Thanks all :)

EDIT: I followed the instructions of the answerer to remove myself from the chat. I clicked "Leave." I'm still getting notifications...What's going on?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136292/avoid-pinging-multiple-users-in-chat

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/939

Comment: Thanks. That's still not a great way to do it, if you ask me. There definitely should be a way to turn off these notifications.

Comment: You're free to upvote any of the feature requests about that... one other thing that might work (but I have to verify that) is change your displayname...(for example NotChatty Alex K)

Comment: I'll have to try that. Any chance you can give me the link to where the feature requests are?

Comment: You could always change your name to something other than Alex. How about letting the community come up with a new name for you which you then have to change legally? :)

Comment: Great idea :) Lets try

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Clicking leave will remove you from the room, however that will not be the end of participation.

If you have been in a given chat room in the past 48 hours, and someone "pings" you (or uses a ping which matches your name in this case), you will get a notification *even if you are no longer in the room*.

Once the 48 hours has expired you will not receive the notifications.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that window. Good catch.

Answer (score 13):

Do you still participate in that chat room? If not, click "leave" and that should take care of the pings.

However, while you're in the room, there unfortunately isn't a way to prevent pings due to shared usernames short of changing your display name to be something more unique.

Comment: Take note the implementation details, these are the effects of allowing user names NOT to be unique.

Comment: @JonH Let's not forget allowing partial username matches to create notifications.